# Error: unexpected string constant "} else {" in R

Tags: r

I want to use the if/else syntax in R with the following code:

```
if (sum("Sample_Sheet.csv" %in% dir(parent_path))) {
      s2c <- read.table(file.path(parent_path, "Sample_Sheet.csv"), header = TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    } else {
      s2c <- read.table(file.path(sleuthDir, "metadata" "metadata.txt"), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    }
```

I just get the error:

```
Error: unexpected string constant in:
"} else {
  s2c <- read.table(file.path(sleuthDir, "metadata" "metadata.txt""
```

But I have no idea what is wrong with my usage, since it works fine "if" I replace the statement after if with a simpler one ...

Would be great to hear some help, every answer I find to these kind of problems just has to do with the { beeing in the wrong line which is not the case for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `,` inbetween `"metadata" "metadata.txt"` like so: `"metadata", "metadata.txt"`.

Comment: Of cause! sorry I bothered you with such a simple typo